# Changing IP of one program

Tags: windows-10, networking, proxy, ip

Is there are any tool or program I can use to run a program with a different IP address without changing my original one. The only thing that worked for me are VMs but they consume much of the hardware resources.

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Why does this program need to run with a different IP address?

Comment: Yes, in Windows 10, you can have multiple IP addresses assigned to a NIC.

Comment: Are you trying to change internal or external, public, IP address? My answer below assumed external but re-reading that seems it may not be the case. As @Mokubai said… what are you *actually* trying to achieve?

Comment: @Mokubai just trying to run only one program with a different IP address

Comment: @Tetsujin think of a game running inside a VM that has a different IP address other than my host OS

Comment: @OmarAhmed What program? To what end? Why? Typically what you want is not easy and if you tell us what you are trying to do we might be able to suggest a better way.

Comment: Please provide the following information about the program: What protocol is it using (HTTP(S)/…)? What is it doing on the network, is it server or client? As Tetsujin asked, is this perhaps about your IP address as visible on the internet?

Comment: @Ramhound.   Windows has supported multiple IP addresses per NIC since at least Windows 7. Unix and Linux for far longer.

Comment: @Mokubai I want to hide my IP address when visiting websites or playing some custom servers games I use a VPN inside a VM and it works fine but it's using much of the hardware resources so I'm looking for alternatives

Comment: @DanielB just creating a virtual environment for any service I use browsing/custom server games

Comment: The only way to change your external IP address is with a VPN. My answer below still stands.

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible.

VPNs do it by actually routing you through a different location, therefore different IP address. Your regular public IP address is not under your control at all, it's governed by your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.  In Windows, you can assign multiple addresses to a given interface.

However, in order for this to work, the application in question would need to be configurable in a way that you can specify it's listening address.  If it is, and you specify one of the addresses assigned to the interface, it should work as planned.

In Windows 10, go to:

Control Panel --> Network and Internet --> View Network Status and Tasks
--> Change Adapter Settings

Right-Click on the Interface you want to configure and select Properties

Select the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) item and click Properties

Click on the Advanced Button

Under the IP addresses sub-window, select Add and add your new address.

Caveats:

1. These are Windows 10 Pro instructions, other versions of Windows may have different steps
2. In order to configure additional network addresses, you cannot use DHCP, so you will need to also statically configure your primary address, gateway and DNS servers.

Keep in mind, these addresses will follow other rules of IP networks and routing.  When adding an address, if it's a completely different subnet address, be sure you have appropriate routing capabilities in place.

The steps are different in UNIX/Linux, but the concepts are the same.

Comment: I don't think i can configure such settings so I'm stuck creating an isolated VM environment and then configuring my VPN/Proxy setting and it's not a practical solution.